# Programmatically altering bulkform actions options

Tags: drupal-8

How can I alter the options in the actions protected property of BulkForm?

Actions are dynamically generated from Content Moderation, but I need to make certain options only available to specific roles.

Comment: can you describe what have you tried?

Comment: I've tried altering the options in a views_pre_build function, but the #actions fragment is protected.  I've tried using ->getBulkOptions and ->getOptions, but they are protected functions.  I've tried creating a new Action Plugin, but you can only have one plugin assigned per action yml.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just using a hook_form_alter and going through the form header to modify the bulk form actions.